# Transferring digital PS3 games to PS4

Tags: psn

Is it possible to transfer digital games from PS3 to PS4? Like i was thinking of getting Destiny for PS3 till i get my PS4 but i don't know if it will transfer over or not. I've seen a lot of things say that you cant but i wanna make sure that it does or doesn't. So just reply back with a reasonable answer so i can chose which Gen. to get it for. I've heard from like a bunch of posts and websites that you cant but i just want the answer.

Comment: Are you asking if Destiny has crossbuy enabled or are you talking about something else? Destiny does not have crossbuy if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

If a game is labelled as cross buy then depending on the game this could mean you buy it once and share it between the PS4 and PS3. Note that cross buy also includes the Vita so you could have a game for example where cross buy means you can play on the PS3 or Vita and not the PS4.

In the case of Destiny I believe there was a special time limited free upgrade option if you brought a PS4 within a certain timeframe (up until Jan 2015). This had nothing to do with cross buy though.

So for Destiny you should certainly purchase it for PS4 as the deal has expired.